# CSS-tables: selector tr:hover is not working as expected?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, frontend, css-tables

Why in this CSS code the background color in (#customers tr:hover) selector is not working for the first tr element which contains the th element and have green background.

```css
#customers {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

#customers td,
#customers th {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 8px;
}

#customers tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

#customers tr:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

#customers th {
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #04aa6d;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<h1>A Fancy Table</h1>

<table id="customers">
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Berglunds snabbköp</td>
    <td>Christina Berglund</td>
    <td>Sweden</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Königlich Essen</td>
    <td>Philip Cramer</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>North/South</td>
    <td>Simon Crowther</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Paris spécialités</td>
    <td>Marie Bertrand</td>
    <td>France</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here is the link: https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_table_fancy

When i read this code from w3schools i was expecting that all tr elements will have a background color of #ddd on hover, but it didn't work for the first one.

is there some kind of restriction on the first tr !?

I am quite new to HTML/CSS so it might be obvious, but it would be nice with some help. Thanks.

Comment: BTW, you should use `<thead>` and `<tbody>` to separate your header row(s) from body rows. And W3Schools is not an authoritative (or even a _good_...) learning resource: I suggest you use https://web.dev instead.

Comment: The hover does work for the first row. But the background color of the `tr` sits *behind* the color of the `th`, so you can't see it. (Test this out by removing the green background.) An alternative for the top row is to chance the background color of the `th` elements on hover.

Comment: but it worked for the rest of <tr> ?

Comment: @RamezSoliman You're right - I my comment described how things were back when IE was still relevant - I've deleted it.

Comment: "but it worked for the rest of <tr> ?" The cells of the other `tr`s don't have a background color. The cell background color (`th`, `td`) will sit *on top of* a row background color.

Answer (score -1):

You did not declare a background color for `td`, only `th`. Therefore, when hover changes the background color of `tr`, the `th` background color does not change. (`th` is on top of `tr`, so the `tr` background color is not visible.) To change the background color of all `th`s in a `tr` when any `th` in the row is hovered, just include an additional selector: `#customers tr:hover th`

```css
#customers {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

#customers td,
#customers th {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 8px;
}

#customers tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

#customers tr:hover,
#customers tr:hover th {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

#customers th {
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #04aa6d;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<h1>A Fancy Table</h1>

<table id="customers">
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Berglunds snabbköp</td>
    <td>Christina Berglund</td>
    <td>Sweden</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Königlich Essen</td>
    <td>Philip Cramer</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>North/South</td>
    <td>Simon Crowther</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Paris spécialités</td>
    <td>Marie Bertrand</td>
    <td>France</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

Hmm, I explained the issue and provided a working solution but got downvoted... Here's more examples to prove my point.

In this example, background-color is declared only for `tr:hover`

```css
tr:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Berglunds snabbköp</td>
    <td>Christina Berglund</td>
    <td>Sweden</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

In this example, `tr` background-color is overruled by the background-color of `th` and `td`

```css
th {
  background-color: #04aa6d;
}

td {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

tr, tr:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Berglunds snabbköp</td>
    <td>Christina Berglund</td>
    <td>Sweden</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This example uses higher specificity with `tr:hover th` and is able to change the background-color on hover.

```css
th {
  background-color: #04aa6d;
}

td {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

tr:hover th {
  background-color: orange;
}

tr:hover td {
  background-color: yellow;
}

tr, tr:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Berglunds snabbköp</td>
    <td>Christina Berglund</td>
    <td>Sweden</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: "the th background color does not change". It *does* change, but it's hidden by the background color of the `th` elements.

Comment: @ralph.m I disagree with your assessment. I believe it wasn't hidden - the background color of `th` did not change with `tr` because the background color of `th` was already declared (and has higher specificity.) If you remove the `th` background color, then it will be effected by `tr` background color.

Comment: @ralph.m is correct, it's not about specificity but about different elements sitting above each other. Check this: https://jsfiddle.net/1oq56dfm/ .. I made the background of th to be content-box and you can clearly see that the background of tr is changing behind the green background of th

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thanks for that example. I didn't dispute that the `tr` background changes, but that the `th` background color does not change (whereas Ralph says it does.) In your example, the `tr` background changes but not `th` background color. Perhaps specificity is the wrong terminology; maybe stacking order would be better? Either way, in order to overwrite the `th` background color when the `tr` is hovered, you'll have to use `tr:hover th`. Am I wrong?

Comment: no one is wrong but all those tr,th,td are a bit confusing. Your code is correct but we cannot really talk about specificity since we have two different elements in play. Don't know what better explanation to give but I think the code is already self-explanatory.

Comment: Reading through all of the comments again, I think that @ralph.m misread my post and then commented based on the misunderstanding. It looks to me like ralph.m thought I had said that the `tr` background color didn't change. Anyway, I'll edit my answer to remove references to specificity since that isn't accurate. The only thing that actually bugs me is receiving downvotes for providing the working solution to the question.